# Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match error in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Hi how to fix this issue in kotlin, I want to assign sum function at var fn,  but it gives error.

Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {

    println(sum(2.0,3.0))
    println(power(2.0,3.0))

    var fn=::sum
}

fun sum(a:Double, b:Double):Double{
    return a+b
}
fun power(a:Double, b:Double):Double{
    return a.pow(b)
}
```

Comment: What are your imports? You're likely importing an existing `sum` function which clashes with your own

Comment: Try it [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjAiLCJjb2RlIjoiXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKGFyZ3M6QXJyYXk8U3RyaW5nPikge1xuXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihzdW0oMi4wLDMuMCkpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihwb3dlcigyLjAsMy4wKSlcblxuICAgIHZhciBmbj06OnN1bVxuICAgIHByaW50KGZuKDIuMSwzLjEpKSAvL2V4cGVjdCA1LjJcbn1cblxuZnVuIHN1bShhOkRvdWJsZSwgYjpEb3VibGUpOkRvdWJsZXtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gYStiXG59XG5cbmZ1biBwb3dlcihhOkRvdWJsZSwgYjpEb3VibGUpOkRvdWJsZXtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gamF2YS5sYW5nLk1hdGgucG93KGEsIGIpXG59IiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiJ9) (Using java math, the ext fun on double was not recognized by the playground).

Comment: @Joffrey only import I have import kotlin.math.pow

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan the code provided here does compile fine as Martin showed (see https://pl.kotl.in/C4IHTYfyt). If you don't have other imports, then the ambiguity should come from other `sum` functions you might have defined in the same package. Do you define other `sum` functions in the same package (potentially in other files)? Also, could you please post the exact error your are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with your above code - it compiles properly. If you have more `sum()` functions in your code, e.g. for summing integers or other number types, then you can choose from them by providing the expected type to the compiler:

```kotlin
var fn: (Double, Double) -> Double = ::sum
```

Comment: nope, I do not have any other sum function in my code, this is complete code which I pasted

Comment: Did you try to use above solution? "Overload resolution ambiguity." clearly says that the compiler "sees" multiple `sum()` functions. For whatever reasons. I believe providing the type explicitly should solve this problem. Note that another `sum()` function does not have to be in the same file for this error to occur. It may be in any file in the same package. The description of the error should list all `sum()` functions and their locations.

Comment: yes it is working fine now